# System of algebraic equations is solvable iff condition on Gröbner basis

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory

I was reading on Gröbner basis in chapter 9 of *Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra*, and while investigating on my own I stumbled upon an interesting result in *Gröbner Bases - Theory and Applications* by *Franz Winkler* which states the following:

> Let $f_1,\ldots,f_m \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, and consider the system $f_1=\dots=f_m=0$. Let $I=(f_1,\ldots,f_m)$ and let $G$ be a normed Gröbner basis of $I$. Then, the system is unsolvable in $\overline{K}^n$ if and only if $1 \in G$.

The main issue I'm having is when trying to prove that $1 \in G$. I was able to show that if $1 \notin G$, then there is no constant polynomial in $G$, and also that if $G \cap K[x_n] = \varnothing$, then by induction I get the desired contradiction.

Any help on the issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is possible to answer this with the weak Nullstellensatz: first of all, the non trivial implication would be:

- $Unsolvable \Rightarrow 1 \in G$ : if $V_{\bar{K}}\left ( I \right ) $ is the set of solutions of your system, because of the weak Nullstellensatz, this would imply  that $I = K\left [ x_1,...,x_n \right ]$. but then, because $G$ is a Gröbner base, $\left ( G \right ) = I$ and $LT\left ( 1 \right ) = 1$ must be divisible by some $LT\left ( g_i \right )$. But then $1 = LT\left ( g_i \right )$, but then it would be $g_i \in K$. But, because G is normed, it should be $1 = g_i \in G$, just what you need.